# I want to implement CRUD apis for a json structure in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Below is the postman json request body structure for which I want create a CRUD api using springboot. This will have a single database table to store all these information. I will be happy to implement the basic post api for this.

Can't really figure out how to go about it. I would very much appreciate your suggestions on how to implement this. Thank you.

```
    
{
        "message":{ 
                                        
                    "to": "/topics/android",

                    "priority": "high",

                    "data": {
                        "deeplink": "deeplink"
                      },

                    "notification": {
                        "title": "",
                        "body": "",
                        "image": ""
                    },
              }
  }
```

Comment: Your JSON request payload is invalid! There are many syntax errors, please revise it first.

Comment: Hi @LHCHIN, I am aware that i have missed the double quotes for those properties but i am really not concerned about the post man request body.

Comment: If you can define the entity to store data, it is easy to implement the CRUD API such as [Accessing JPA Data with REST](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) or [Introduction to Spring Data REST](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-intro).

Comment: So i will need to create three entity classes but then how to use those fields and then map to a single database table?

Comment: It depends. For example. if you are using NoSQL database (e.g. MongoDB), you can create just ONE entity class. If you are using relational database, 1, 3 or more entities can achieve the same thing.

Comment: @LHCHIN can you please suggest how to proceed with this. I am using postgresql